# Why is colomap not applied when I use style in pandas plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following issue. If I want to plot a line chart without using any style with a colormap this works fine. However, as soon as I apply a style the colormap is not picked up.

Let's make an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[100, 100],[105, 110],[107, 118],[112, 110]])
my_cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("GnBu_d", len(df.columns)).as_hex())

df.plot(colormap=my_cmap, alpha=0.8, rot=0, xticks=df.index, linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

This plot generates a correct color scheme:

[image]

However when using the style parameter

```
df.plot(colormap=my_cmap, alpha=0.8, rot=0, xticks=df.index, linewidth=2, style=['o-', 's:'])
plt.show()
```

it overrides somehow that:

[image]

How can I use the style with the desired colormap?

Comment: [This method](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0409521665bd436a10aea7e06336066bf07ff057/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L659) applies the colors from the colormap only when no style is given. So apparently this is intended.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Is there away around this?

Comment: Mhh, not sure. Since you also cannot pass `df.plot(color=[my_cmap(0),my_cmap(1)], alpha=0.8, rot=0, xticks=df.index, linewidth=2, style=['o', 's'])` there might be a bug involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0409521665bd436a10aea7e06336066bf07ff057/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L659) the colors from the colormap are only applied when no style is given.

I do not know if there is a solution available from within the pandas plotting wrapper. A workaround would be to temporarily set a different color cycler when plotting. Pandas plotting wrapper will use the matplotlib color cycler, such that the following would produce the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[100, 100],[105, 110],[107, 118],[112, 110]])

cc = plt.cycler("color", sns.color_palette("GnBu_d", len(df.columns)))
with plt.style.context({"axes.prop_cycle" : cc}):
    df.plot(alpha=0.8, rot=0, xticks=df.index, linewidth=2, style=['o-', 's:'])
plt.show()
```

[image]